# Neutral wire to ground pantry light

Tags: wiring

Helping a friend replace the pantry light. The existing set up was a single double light switch, One switch was the 2nd location of a three way switch to the kitchen overhead lighting, The other switch was very strange and controlled the pantry light. Somebody had drilled a half inch hole straight through the back of the plastic box exiting through the drywall inside the pantry. They then ran 18 gauge lamp wire through the hole, And ran it up the drywall surface inside the pantry, Holding it in place with drywall screws, And mounted a sconce light to the wall inside the pantry (No box or anything, All the connections were in the light housing box). Inside the electric box in the kitchen the 18 gauge lamp wire that came through the hole was attached to the double switch, With the fraying end smashed into the screw, It looks like the neutral wires were attached to the grounds on the switch. It worked but it looked very problematic. My guess is that when the house was built there was no light inside the pantry and the previous owner tried to fix that…

Attempt #1: I cut the power and disconnected all the wires and the switch in the single gang box, And then removed the entire box itself. I than enlarged the hole for a old work double gang box, And ran a new 14/2 wire up inside the wall into the pantry ceiling and out a 6 inch hole for a new puck light. I went back to install two new switches one for the pantry ceiling light and one for the three-way. And that is where disaster struck. None of the wires were neutral except the one neutral wire leading to the new puck light. I couldn’t figure it out so I hired Electrician.

Attempt #2: The electrician came in and was able to make the three way switch work. But he was at a loss on how to make the pantry ceiling light work because there was no neutral wire. He proposed cutting through the wall and potentially damaging the backsplash to try and pull a neutral wire from one of the kitchen outlets. The only other option he suggested was attaching the neutral wire from the pantry light to the grounding wire, Which he said was not a professional solution but also demonstrated how it worked. The decision was to just attach the neutral wire to the grounding wire to avoid any destruction of the black splash. And everything is working now.

Question: understanding that some risk has been assumed here trying to assess how much risk (a lot, a little?) The electrician pointed out that the neutral wire is attached to the ground at the panel, So there’s that. I’ve read about light switches that don’t require a neutral wire and was wondering if I should tell my friend to try that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems mess up badly.  The best idea is to start over and do it right, with junction/light boxes and proper cable, and switch/s.  A single light with a single switch is not rocket science and should be quite simple.  It looks like the others tried to get power for light from a source they should not have used and made your life complicated.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the insides of all switch boxes in the circuit please?

Comment: There's quite a bit wrong with the wiring your photo shows, and not just the ground being used as a circuit conductor. If your State is like mine, this mess will also have to be disclosed as unpermitted, uninspected electrical work being done on the house in the event of sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two key concepts:

- Old switch boxes don't always have neutral

New switch boxes are supposed to have neutral, even if it is not needed right now, because a future smart switch, WiFi switch, timer, motion sensor, etc. may need neutral. That also, conveniently, means that *most* new switch boxes will include the right wires (always hot and neutral) to be able to power additional receptacles, separately switched lights, etc.

Because this is a common problem, there is a *limited* workaround permitted where switches that require some power for their own internal functions, and therefore require a return current path, to use ground instead of neutral. However, for safety reasons this is extremely limited. **You can't legitimately power an actual light this way.**

Note that this problem is not limited to 3-way switches (which have additional problems, see below). Many older homes have switches wired with a *switch loop*, where one wire is always hot and the other wire is switched hot. You can generally tell if this is the case because the switch will be wired with a single black/white cable. If a switch is wired with black and red or with two blacks that come from different cables then you will *usually* find white neutrals lurking in the box. But remember, while neutral is always white (except sometimes gray in conduit), white is not always neutral!

- 3-Way switches are complicated

There are a number of different ways to wire a set of 3-way switches. With most of them, at least until recent code changes regarding neutral, it is perfectly normal for one of the switches to have neutral but not always hot, or to have always hot but not neutral. In other words, with 3-way switches there is *often* one switch where you can pull both always hot and neutral to power a separately switched light and *almost always* one switch (and sometimes both!) where you **can't** pull both always hot and neutral to power a separately switched light.

The end result is: You can't do what you want with what you've got. Which is why the previous owner hacked things up in a really bad way. Actually, as you already know, the previous owner violated numerous other very serious code rules (too small wire, wrong type of cable, improper routing of cables, etc.). Your electrician **should have been able to figure this out** and not just fix the other code violations but actually understand the basic 3-way switch "can't have it all" problem.

---

There are really only two good fixes here:

- New cable

Run a new 14/2 or 12/2 cable from another location to power this switch/light. This could be from the same circuit - e.g., from the other 3-way switch box, or it could be from another circuit - e.g., a nearby receptacle. Note however that if it comes from a different circuit then it can't be on the same yoke like the two switches in a single gang as in the pictures.

- Smart switches

Many smart switches only require two wires from the "main" switch to the light, freeing up the third wire for other use. It can be quite a bit tricky figuring it all out, and not all smart switches work in a way that will solve this problem. You will probably need a smart switch with a "wireless remote". This type of remote looks just like a regular switch, but it lets you reuse the wires for other stuff, like powering a new switch/light. To figure this out, we'll need pictures of the inside of the other 3-way switch box.